# Backbone.js event binding with phonegap + android gives "blue wrap" on click

Tags: android, cordova, backbone.js, dom-events, backbone-events

I face with really weird case, when im binding trough backbone.js events, my android phonegap app get "blue wrap frame" on click.

The iOS version is alright.

I attached screenshot:
[image: On trigger]

[image: regular]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "blue wrap" could be part of the default css for your mobile device. You can try adding:

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; }
```